# Vue cli for personal use alternative way to run

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

I made a Vue app with Bootstrap-Vue, Express(nodejs) and MySQL. I'm using vue-cli and It's currently in development mode. I've created a SPA(server and client in different folders), and I'm compiling with vscode terminal using:

```
cd client
npm run serve
```

and

```
cd server
node index.js
```

My problem is: I don't have a domain because it's only for personal use(and I don't have money), and to open the vscode and doing the rotine takes 20-60 seconds. Is there an alternative and quickly way to run my vue app?

Comment: You can host it on github for free with a github domain (yourrepo.github.io)...see here: https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html. Alternatively, you can get a free domain here: https://www.freenom.com/en/freeandpaiddomains.html and host it for free with [render.com](https://render.com) (I use render.com, and it works great for me)

Comment: Also, you could put all these commands into a batch file and when you click on it, it'll run these commands without you having to type anything. But Vue will still take time to prepare the files for serving...so it won't be instant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of a couple of things you can do.

### 1) Get a free domain and free hosting

As I mentioned in the comments, you can get a free domain at [freenom.com](https://www.freenom.com/en/index.html?lang=en), and host it for free with [render.com](https://render.com). This has some pros and cons to it.

**Pros:**

- It's free.
- You can access it from anywhere.
- No need to setup every time, just enter the URL.

**Cons:**

- You probably won't get to choose the domain's extention. It'll probably be a `.tk` domain or something not very well known.
- I believe that you need to renew it annually, but that's with any domain.
- Anyone an access it, though it's not like everyone will know about it.
- Needs an internet connection, but this isn't a problem if your app already needs internet access to function.

You can also host it with Github. Here's [instructions](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html#github-pages) on how to do that, and [here's](https://pages.github.com/) instructions to set up Github pages.

See [Deploying a Node Express App](https://render.com/docs/deploy-node-express-app) or [Deploying a Vue.js App](https://render.com/docs/deploy-vue-js) for instructions on how to set up hosting on render.com

### 2) Automate what you are doing now

Typing takes time, and you can create a batch file to run those commands for you. Depending on what OS you are on (I'm doing this for windows), you can create a file, e.g. **OpenApp.bat** and place inside what you are already doing:

```
cd C://ABSOLUTE_PATH_TO_CLIENT
npm run serve
cd C://ABSOLUTE_PATH_TO_SERVER
node index.js
start localhost:8080 or whatever the path is
```

Then just double click it and it'll run these tasks for you. I haven't tested this idea yet so not sure if it'll work.

### 3) Build your app

A third option would be to build your app, then serve it. This would eliminate the time `npm run serve` takes, and you can host it instead with `serve`.

Install `serve`:

```
npm install -g serve
```

...and build your app:

```
npm run build
```

...and serve the app:

```
serve -s dist
```

It should instantly serve your app without any long processing time.

You can create a batch file to do this also (again, I'm not sure if it'll work):

```
cd C://ABSOLUTE_PATH_TO_CLIENT
serve -s dist
cd C://ABSOLUTE_PATH_TO_SERVER
node index.js
start localhost:5000 or whatever the path is
```

This should be faster than option 2...but editing your app requires it being re-built each time to see the changes.

Comment: Thanks, I did the third part and everything is Ok, though I use linux fedora so instead of the batch file I need to create a Shell Script. You helped me so much ツ